# how to make environment variable in "/etc/supervisord.conf" work in shell or python?

Tags: python, django, unix

I would like to add an environment variable in the file “/etc/supervisord.conf”, but it doesn’t work. Can anyone please help? What I did is as below:

in the file /etc/supervisord.conf, I added below line:

```
environment=LOY_ENVIRONMENT="dev"
```

then in Unix prompt, I run below and got error.

`> python  -c "import os; print(os.environ['LOY_ENVIRONMENT'])"
   Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'LOY_ENVIRONMENT'`

Below doesn't work either. I tried reboot the server as well.

```
echo $LOY_ENVIRONMENT
```

Comment: What if you add the environment to your `bashrc` or `zshrc`?

Comment: supervisord.conf configuration only applies to things launched by supervisord. Typing `python` into your terminal is not launching python via supervisord.

Comment: One a side note, python 2.x is EOL.